$L^2$ approximation of delta functions on real algebraic varieties and asymptotic bounds
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$.  Consider a probability measure $\mu$ on $X(\mathbb{R})$, absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure induced by a Riemannian metric on $X(\mathbb{R})$.  Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$, and denote by $H^0(X, L^d)$ the space of global sections of $L^d$.
For a point $x \in X(\mathbb{R})$, define the quantity
$$ \delta_d(x) = \inf_{s \in H^0(X, L^d), s(x) \neq 0} \frac{\|s\|_{L^2(X(\mathbb{R}), \mu)}}{|s(x)|}, $$
where $\|s\|_{L^2(X(\mathbb{R}), \mu)}$ is the $L^2$ norm of $s$ with respect to $\mu$. This measures the "cost" of approximating the delta function at $x$ by global sections of $L^d$.
We can define the average cost of approximation as
$$ \Delta_d = \int_{X(\mathbb{R})} \delta_d(x) d\mu(x). $$
Question:  Does there exist a constant $C > 0$, depending only on $X$, $L$, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mu/d\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure), such that
$$ \limsup_{d \to \infty} \frac{\log \Delta_d}{d} \leq C? $$
Furthermore, if such a constant exists, can we relate it to geometric invariants of $X$ and the measure $\mu$, such as the volume of $X(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to $\mu$, the curvature of $X(\mathbb{R})$, or the singularities of the Radon-Nikodym derivative?
I tried dabbling with using Bertini's theorem and transversality arguments to construct families of sections of $L^d$ with controlled behavior on $X(\mathbb{R})$. But I haven't gotten any tangible results yet.
